# Does p value depend on n for binomial distribution?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution

Im new to statistics,I have a sample with P=0.034 and n=1000, can I say the parameters for population are n and 0.034 ?

Comment: The number 0.034 is an unbiased estimate of the true binomial parameter p. It is not the population parameter. The p-value does changes as the sample size changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If either was dependent on the other, they wouldn't be separate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

We can define the likelihood of observing $k$ successes in a binomial distribution as 
$$
f(k) ={n \choose p} p^k (1-p)^{(1-k)}.
$$

This means that for a given binomial distribution with $n$ and $p$, we can calculate the number of successes. $n$ is simply the number of individual experiments that are run, and $p$ is the probability of a given experiment resulting in success. Neither of the parameters is generally a function of the other.